# How to customize UIIMagePickerCoctroller in Captured Video Frame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uikit

I'm trying to customize the UIImagepickercontroller as below image,

[image]

But right now the Uiimagepickercontroller shows like below.

[image]

Can anyone please give an idea on how to customize the UIImagepickercontroller in showing the Video ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to customize UIImagepickercontroller, then you will have to use AVcapturemanager.
i have posted sample code provided by APPLE, that how to customize UIImagepickercontroller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112

It will be helpful to you.. but you will have to make neccessary changes in it.

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: @ NiravPatel I would like to customize the view, after captured the video. As you seen in screen shot with editing the video,Play the video options et.., Please let me know how to do that.